# Word passwords in SharePoint

Tags: word, password

We have been sharing a protected word document on sharepoint.

Once saved it can be opened with password and then edited and saved but the next time we try to open it the password is rejected.

How do we get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening the Word file in the browser or the client application?  I doubt that this would work in the browser.  My personal suggestion would be to use SharePoint permissions to secure the file instead of a password, unless it is a business requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is not SharePoint related, same problem occurs when using an internal shared drive.  Was not my choice to password protect (I would have recommended as above i.e. using permissions). Looks like I'll have to redo all the changes I made (original copy is available).Thanks